# exit awk if no input

Tags: awk, grep

I need that awk would return exit code 1 if:

- no input from grep to awk was provided
- second field is empty or does not exist

It is working when grep finds  "SOME_PHRASE", but if this phrase does not exit, return code ($?) is 0.

```
grep -m1 -i '^SOME_PHRASE' test.txt | awk '{ if (length($val)==0 || $val=="" || length($2)==0) exit 1; else print $2; }'
```

example of test.txt

```
Test1 1234  
Phrase 214324
```

Expected output:

```
$ echo $?  
1
```

Comment: You are right, I can do it only with awk. For example I tried awk '/SOME_PHRASE/  {if (val=="" || $2=="") exit 1; else print $2;}' test.txt, but still does not work

Comment: add sample input and expected output for various cases...

Comment: There seems to be some issue with the if condition. I tried "grep -m1 -i '^SOME_PHRASE' test.txt | awk '{ if (0) exit 1; else exit 5 }'" and this is returning 5.. I tried $ cat test.txt
test.txt
SOME_PHRASE
SOME_PHRASEerewte
 awk '/SOME_PHRASE/ {if (val=="" || $2=="") exit 1; else print $2;}' test.txt and it is returning 1 .echo $?
1. May be val is getting populated from somewhere.

Comment: Added example of input and expected output

Comment: The examples could be made a *lot* clearer.  I couldn't tell what you were trying to do at all until I read your self-answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed combine `awk` and `grep`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{rv=1}                      # Default return value is 1
     tolower($0) ~ /^some_phrase/{    # Case insensitive search 
         if($2 != ""){                # If $2 is not empty,
            print $2                  # print the value,
            rv=0                      # and set the return value
         } 
         exit                         # one match, do not process any more line 
     } 
     END{exit rv}
' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve what I wanted.

```
grep -m1 -i 'SOME_PHRASE' test.txt | awk 'END { if (NR==0 || $2=="")  exit 1; else print $2;}'
```

Answer (score 1):

More straight forward:

```
$ awk 'toupper($1) ~ /^SOME_PHRASE/ { if ($2) { print $2; exit 0 } else { exit 1 } } END { exit 1 }' test.txt
```

The first field is changed to uppercase and compared against the uppercase pattern. If matching, and if there exist a second field, that field will be printed and the script exits with a zero exit status, otherwise (no second field) it will exit with an exit status of 1.  If the pattern never matches, the script will exit with an exit status of 1 once it reaches the end of input.

Comment: Saved me the trouble of writing it.  :)  That's exactly what I was thinking when I finally understood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that `awk` is perfectly capable of doing what `grep` does here, you could also explicitly check for empty input in `awk` and then return a one. Here an `END` block checks the number of lines (records) processed:

```
$ echo foo | grep bar | awk 'END {if (NR == 0) exit  }' ; echo "exit value $?"
exit value 1
```

Or, use the shell to get the return code of the failing process in the pipeline, even if it's not the last one. I don't think the standard shell can do that, but e.g. in Bash, `set -o pipefail`:

```
$ set -o pipefail 
$ echo foo | grep bar | awk '{exit 0}' ; echo "exit value $?"
exit value 1
```

(Bash also has `PIPESTATUS` if you want to look at the return values from all the processes in the pipeline.)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider moving everything inside one roof/tool to make it simple:

```
grep -qE '^SOME_PHRASE.*[^[:space:]]' yourfile

perl -0777ne 'exit !/^SOME_PHRASE.*?\S/m' yourfile

sed -ne '/^SOME_PHRASE.*[^[:space:]]/q;$q1' yourfile
```

## Output

For the data shown, immediately after running either of the above commands, we run:

```
echo "$?"
1
```

## Brief

`Perl` `slurps` the whole of yourfile and looks for the keyword at the beginning of a line, which is enabled for `multiline` strings using `//m` modifier. The `!` is there to account for the fact that `SUCCESS` in `Perl` & `Unix` worlds is complementary.

`Sed` is operated in `don't print unless asked for` mode `-n` and assuming `GNU sed` which has the `q` command that includes the exit status as well.